# Losses/Profits Calculations

Tags: calculus, summation, computational-mathematics

I have a case study (see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD2Ig.png)) and i am struggling to understand the calculations. The case study is on Credit Risk.

The picture shows the data from a bank in the last 12 months including write offs, loses and profits.

I need to understand how the below are calculated ?

1. Total Losses
2. Profits

My first thought for profit is the below relationship :

Profit = Annual Income - Total Losses

However, when i use data from January, for example, the outcome is not correct.

$£288,000 - £229.677 = £58,323 $

Any help it will be appreciated :)

Below is a further description of the variables:

- Accounts Opened in a month
- Average Risk score, for the accounts opened in the month
- Annualised Income (Income over a 12 month period)
- Average Overdraft Amount Granted
- Average Write-Off Balance &
- Annualised Losses (Losses over a 12 month period)

Antonis

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than images, review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: thank you for your comments. I had a look in both links and tried to improve my post. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profit = Annual income + Average Granted Overdraft Limit + Average Write-Off Balance - Total Losses

Comment: thank you for your answer